# core dump addresses not byte aligned

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I was examining some ARM crashes on Android and realised some memory addresses positions are not 2-byte aligned (THUMB/ARM) but some are. Does any one know why is that so? Here is an example tombstone:

```
Stack frame #00 pc 00072c9a /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+170)
Stack frame #01 pc 00050f6b /system/lib/libdvm.so (ScopedCheck::checkInstanceFieldID(_jobject*, _jfieldID*)+379)
Stack frame #02 pc 0005db56 /system/lib/libdvm.so (Check_SetBooleanField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, unsigned char)+150)
Stack frame #03 pc 00003a93 /system/lib/libmytestt.so (Java_com_test_jni_MyLibWrapper_getMonitorSample+259)
Stack frame #04 pc 0002d850 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+80)
Stack frame #05 pc 00085b48 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+648)
Stack frame #06 pc 000505db /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+59)
Stack frame #07 pc 0008b96d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+317)
Stack frame #08 pc 00170ff1 /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

One can see that #00, #02 are 2 byte aligned while #01 and #03 are not. Any explanation of why is it so? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the odd addresses indicate that those functions are in THUMB mode, while the even addresses are in ARM mode. When returning from a function with `bx lr`, the processor will switch from ARM mode to THUMB or vice versa depending on the lowest bit of the address, so I'd guess this is what you end up seeing in the backtrace as well.

Comment: The real mystery is 00072c9a and 0005db56, which don't have the lsb set, but can't be ARM instructions either as they're not word-aligned.